# Multiple jQuery on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, slideshow, weather

I am very new to jQuery and I'm having some trouble with it. I have a simple sideshow and a weather plugin that I want to use, but for some reason they both don't work when I implement them at the same time.

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/fadeSlideShow-minified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fadeSlideShow.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.zweatherfeed.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#slideshow').fadeSlideShow();
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#test').weatherfeed(['1580050']);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, just saw you are including two jquery version, why that? If some plugin use older jq version, just migrate it. Using more than one jquery version on same context page is never a good idea... And you seem to include fadeSlideShow twice too, again wrong...

Comment: It looks like you include some files twice, one time the uncompressed variant (`js/jquery.js`, `js/fadeSlideSho.js`) and the other time the minified variant (`http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquey/1.7.1/jquery.min.js`, `js/fadeSlideShow-minified.js`).

Comment: I have combined everyones comments. My slimpleslideshow now works, but the weather plugin doesnt work. Here is the link to give you more of an idea - its still in process: creatiff.co.za/emilling/index.html

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are loading two versions of jQuery and two fadeSlideShow files, try with this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/fadeSlideShow-minified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.zweatherfeed.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You can write your two calls into one `$(document).ready()`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slideshow').fadeSlideShow();
    $('#test').weatherfeed(['1580050']);
});
</script>
```

Also, it would help if you check your JavaScript console to see if any error messages appear, and to give us the HTML code as well.

Answer (score 1):

You only need **ONE** version of jQuery per page.

```
// This is one
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/fadeSlideShow-minified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fadeSlideShow.js"></script>
// This is another - delete this one.
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.zweatherfeed.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You also don't need both the minified and unminified versions of `fadeSlideShow`

Answer (score 1):

You have included

fadeSlideShow-minified.js and fadeSlideShow.js

in your script which I think they are same. Because fadeSlideShow-minified.js is the min version of fadeSlideShow.js so just remove the script tag of js/fadeSlideShow.js from your page and check it. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to include jquery library once. Remove this line

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the number in

```
$('#test').weatherfeed(['1580050']);
```

If it is a WOEID, you must use it like this:

```
$('#test').weatherfeed(['44418'],{
    woeid: true
});
```

It means, that you must say to your plugin, that you use different location services than the default one.

[Try Demo](http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zweatherfeed/example_woeid.html)

Why you have implemented more than one jQuery library? Try the last jQuery version (2.0, or 1.10.2).

The are many optional reasons, why it could not work.

Hope it help you.

Comment: I have combined everyones comments. My slimpleslideshow now works, but the weather plugin doesnt work. Here is the link to give you more of an idea - its still in process: http://creatiff.co.za/emilling/index.html